# Обновление списка с данными из сети, как в приложениях ВКонтакте, G+ etc

Tags: android, java, pulltorefresh, вконтакте

**Дано**: есть новостное приложение, парсер сайта. Работа с обновлениями списка реализована с помощью библиотеки PullToRefresh.

**Надо**: хочу сделать, как в приложениях ВКонтакте, G+ etc. Т.е. загружать новые статьи,  потянув вниз и увидев анимацию в ActionBare; загружать предыдущие автоматически, как только юзер дойдёт до конца списка. Ну и чтоб при поступлении новых данных из сервиса выкидывалась сверху кнопка "открыть 7 новых".

**Вопрос**: надо свой велосипед писать или есть готовые решения? Если есть, то есть ли официальные гугловые, типа как с Navigation Drawer-ом? И есть ли по всему этому какие-либо руководства\ примеры?

*Спрашиваю тут, т.к. в своё время кучу времени потратил на гугленье того же Navigation Drawer-а, гугл мне вовсю выдавал устаревшие статьи по неофиц. библиотекам. Хотя бы направление, в котором копать, хотелось бы) Заранее всем спасибо!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Для свайпа вниз и с анимацией в `ActionBar` есть уже стандартный андроидовский [SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html).
2. Подгрузка старых - [GitHub - InfiniteListView](https://github.com/murcy/InfiniteListView), [How to Implement an Infinitely Scrolling List in Android](http://www.avocarrot.com/blog/implement-infinitely-scrolling-list-android/).
3. Как и написал [[@Deadkenny](/users/17344/deadkenny)](/users/17344/deadkenny) сделать самому плашку, либо приспособить, к примеру, [SuperToasts](https://github.com/JohnPersano/SuperToasts).

Comment: Спасибо, похоже, это как раз то, что я и хотел узнать! =)

Answer (score 3):

Библиотек нет, все вручную.

- Подгрузка новостей при скроле. Нужно следить за положением скрола ListView, когда подходишь к концу списка - запускаешь подгрузку. Для примера можно посмотреть исходники [google ioshed](https://github.com/google/iosched).
- Подгрузка новостей с плашкой "открыть 7-мь новых"(кстати не пишут 7-мь, т.к. получается слово семьмь) - время от времени посылать запрос к API и если будут новые новости, то показывать плашку. [Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/?hl=ru).

Для всего этого дела гугл использует свои [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html). Достаточно удобно, хотя немного запутана логика, на мой взгляд. Для старых версий есть совместимость в Support library v7.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку на Loader. Почитал доки. Правильно ли я понял, что основные отличия Loader (AsyncTaskLoader) от AsyncTask, коий я сейчас пользую, в том, что обновить адаптер списка (например) можно из активити прямо (в onLoadFinished()), а не из onPostExecute(), как в AsyncTask? И что задача в бэкграунде не зависима от измений конфигурации (типа поворота экрана) и приостанавливается автоматически в onPause()?

И таки да - с "7-мь" очепятался. УжО поправил) Извиняю себя тем, что уважаемый модератор @Виталина ♦ тоже пропустил(а(?)) этот момент, правя мой вопрос на предмет пропущенных запятых

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, да, основное достоинство - неизменность во время изменения конфигурации. Просто инициализируется Loader и кэшированные данные приходят в onLoadFinished(). Также можно иметь несколько загрузчиков в одном фрагменте.